# Monitor Implementation (Synchronization)

Tags: c, operating-system, synchronization

The assignment is to develop a monitor, by the name of matchmaker.
We have a routine: self(); that returns the thread's id.

The  matchmaker method must do the following:
Threads that call this routine "trade" tids. When a thread A calls make_match() and a value B is returned, this means that that thread ID B also called the make_match routine. For a pair to be possible make_match() can send the thread to sleep, at will.

For the mutex and condition variables pthread.h mustbe used.

This is the code I came up with but because this is a written assignment I cannot evaluate it's correctness. I would like some feedback on wether this could work or not. Thank you in advance.

```
unsigned int tid1,tid2;
pthread_cond_t pwp;
pthread_mutex_t m;

unsigned int math_maker() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(m);

    if (first) {
        tid1 = self();
        first = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(m);
        wait(pwp);
        pthread_mutex_lock(m);  
    } else {
        tid2 = self();
        pthrad_condition_broadcast(pwp);
    }

    //Critical section that requires the matching to be possible

    pthread_mutex_unlock(m);

    if (tid1 == self())
        return tid2;
    if (tid2 == self());
        return tid1
}
```

Comment: I don't see what prevents you from evaluating your code's correctness yourself.  Write a test program around it to help you.  Heck, start out simply by compiling it to an object file without trying to link it to form a program.  That would at least help you root out misspellings and syntax errors.

Comment: It's odd that you are using pthreads, but not that library's type for thread IDs (`pthread_t`).  Does your `self()` function indeed return `unsigned int` instead?

Comment: Overall, you have several problems in your code, many of which a compiler will reveal to you (be sure to turn up the warning level), and a few that it probably wouldn't.  Update your code at least to correct those of the former kind, then we'll talk.